# What do you do if part of your math equation is undefined?

Tags: trigonometry

I have to write trigonometry problems for my math project, and I ended writing one I couldn't solve: $sin(sin^{-1} \ 60 ^\circ + sin^{-1} \frac{3}{5})$.
I'll take you as far as I can.

1. $sin(sin^{-1} \ 60 ^\circ + sin^{-1} \frac{3}{5}) = sin(sin^{-1} \ 60 ^\circ)*cos(sin^{-1} \frac{3}{5}) +cos(sin^{-1} \ 60 ^\circ) * sin(sin^{-1} \frac{3}{5})$
2. $undefined * \frac{4}{5} + undefined * \frac{3}{5}$

Is the answer really just undefined? Why is that that? Why can't I take an angle as an input?

Edit: yes, I know I could just have used a valid argument, but I wanted to see what would happen.

Comment: How exactly did you wind up with "$\sin^{-1}(60^\circ)$" in your question? That doesn't really make sense at all. (Not every expression you write down is actually meaningful, after all.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber at first it was $sin 60^\circ$ but then i changed it to $sin^{-1}$ but not 60 degrees. I wanted to see if it was possible to solve

Answer (score 1):

"$\sin^{-1}(60^\circ)$" does not make (too much) sense. It is the functions $\sin, \cos, \tan$ etc. that take an angle as an *argument*: not $\sin^{-1}, \cos^{-1}, \tan^{-1}$. Those latter functions produce angles as their *output*.

One could formally try to plug the number $60$, or perhaps the number $\pi/3$ (knowing that $60^\circ=\pi/3$) into $\sin^{-1}$ (which is probably what your calculator tried): the result will be defined only if the number you are plugging is between $-1$ and $1$, otherwise the result is undefined. (Note $\pi/3\approx 3.1416\ldots/3>1$ and certainly $60>1$.)

Comment: well let's just say i wrote 100, it would still come out undefined. Where would I go from there?

Comment: @Wisesequoia Why don't you plug a number between $-1$ and $1$? Like you already did with $\frac{3}{5}$? Maybe choose $\frac{4}{5}$ this time?

Comment: you are correct. I totally could, but I just wanted to know if anything would happen if I didn't plug in valid argument.

Comment: In the range of real numbers, there is no number $x$ such that $\sin x=100$, that is why $\sin^{-1}(100)$ is undefined. There sure are complex numbers with this property, which you can find (remember that $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ so you want to solve $100=\frac{z-\frac{1}{z}}{2i}$, which is a quadratic equation in $z$, then use complex logarithm to solve $e^{ix}=z$...) - not sure if you want to go *that* far.

Comment: yeah that's pretty complicated, so what would happen if I gave the equation at the its last form? is it undefined?

Comment: This is not an *equation*, it is an *expression*, and yes, it is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119264/discussion-between-wise-sequoia-and-stinking-bishop).